# Javascript how to convert object with values into object of key value pair

Tags: javascript

How do i convert a `set` object with only values into object with key value pairs containing same value as `key` ?

```
let set = new Set()
set.add(a)
set.add(example)
console.log(set)
//OUTPUT {"a", "example"}

//perform some operation to get result below ?
```

to

`{"a":"a","example":"example"}`

Comment: But `{"a", "example"}` is invalid, did you mean `["a", "example"]`?

Comment: my bad it is actually a set let me rephrase the question

Comment: why do you want to do this?

Comment: @NickParsons i need the data in a particular format

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Set has an [entries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set/entries) method which you can pass down to [Object.fromEntries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries)

```js
let set = new Set();
set.add("a");
set.add("example");

const result = Object.fromEntries(set.entries());

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

Spread the set to an `Array` and reduce that to an `Object`

```js
const set = new Set();
set.add("a");
set.add("b");
set.add("valueC");
console.log(
  [...set]
    .reduce( (acc, val) => ({...acc, [val]: val}), {} )
);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could convert it to an array of value and do the [`Array.prototype.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

```js
let set = new Set()
set.add('a')
set.add('example')

const res = Array.from(set).reduce((acc, val) => ({ ...acc, [val]: val }), {})

console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set/forEach):

```js
const set = new Set();
set.add('a');
set.add('example');
const result = {};
set.forEach(i => result[i] = i);

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score -3):

If you meant `["a", "example"]`:

```js
var data=["a", "example"];
var obj=data.map(item=>({item:item}));
console.log(obj);
```